Как сделать так чтобы на каждой странице выбирались разные данные
Как выбрать данные из БД через переменную, полученную через $_GET
Вот что пробую, но пишет ошибку:
$dbnum = $_GET['id'];
$result = $db->query('SELECT * FROM `$dbnum` ORDER BY id DESC'); 


да,  извиняюсь, ошибку приложил

Это просто ужасно. Пожалуйста, никогда не делайте так. Объясните, почему вы решили что вам нужно получать имя таблицы из браузера, и вам расскажут, как сделать правильно.

А не надо на переменных экономить! $sql = 'SELECT * FROM `$dbnum` ORDER BY id DESC'; - и смотри, что получилось...

@Akina получилось то же самое. Вы всегда говорили, что не интересуетесь РНР. К чему этот комментарий?

@Ипатьев я решил использовать так, потому что хочу чтобы на каждой новой странице одной системы фоток, была разная база данных.. и решил выбирать базу данных из url. пока что как сделать по другому в голову не пришло, а для каждой новой базой данных отдельную страницу создавать не собираюсь. поэтому как-то так. нужен комментарий и помощь специалиста..)

Помощь специалиста: 1. то, что вы называете базой данных, на самом деле называется таблицей. 2. Таблица для одинаковых данных всегда должна быть одна. 3. Имя таблицы всегда пишется в коде и не передаётся из браузера никогда. Поэтому вам надо сделать одну таблицу, добавить в неё колонку "page" и выбирать  записи для каждой страницы с помощью этой колонки. Например SELECT * FROM photo WHERE page=?

Для того, чтобы переменная подставилась в строку, нужно использовать двойные кавычки, а не одинарные. "SELECT * FROM `$dbnum` ORDER BY id DESC"

@ВикторКарев это не слишком полезная информация в данном случае. И лучше было воздержаться от демонстрации своих глубоких познаний в синтаксисе РНР

@Ипатьев о, понял, спасибо большое! я решил так сделать, потому что когда я раньше данные брал из одной таблицы, и брал только последние 30 через LIMIT 30 в запросе к табл, то страница ООООЧЕНЬ долго загружалась. отсюда такое не очень умное решение использовать разные таблицы для разных страниц

Если такой примитивный запрос выполняется так долго, то какая-то проблема с сервером. И надо чинить сервер, а не плодить таблицы

Нууу))) может дело в моей таблице где овермного фотографий в кодировке BLOB...

Разумеется. Хранить картинки в БД - это еще одни дурацкая идея

@Ипатьев так. а где тогда? у меня система загрузок фотографий на сайт, где юзер сам может опубликовать фото на сайт. хранить в будущем 1000 фотографий на своем диске точно не вариант, тем более не думаю что возможно загружать фотографии ко мне на диск с сайта

Во-первых, непонятно, с чего вы решили что невозможно, если все так и делают - хранят фото на диске. Во-вторых, даже БД хранит данные не в безвоздушном пространстве, а на том же самом диске, в одном большом файле.

@Ипатьев прям на диск личного компьютера владельца? ну в моем случае ноутбука

Ну если сайт будет расположен на твоем ноутбуке, то конечно тут беда.

@Ипатьев нет конечно)) давайте все таки не переходить на ты, а во вторых мой сайт уже давно есть на хостинге) можете глянуть (skymoments)

А при чем здесь вообще какой-то личный диск или владелец? Речь о диске сервера, разумеется.

@Ипатьев теперь понятно понятно. спасибо, туплю еще, совсем "зеленый" в программировани тем более с работой бд и дисками, извиняюсь

@Ипатьев получилось то же самое .. К чему этот комментарий? Вы пропустили маленький, но очень важный кусочек моей фразы: "смотри, что получилось". Неявно я предполагаю, что автор не только сам посмотрит, но и нам покажет. И, поскольку там в запросе явно присутствует синтаксическая ошибка, хоть кто-нибудь её увидит и назовёт...

@Akina сорри, не догадался куда именно смотреть. Впрочем, автор вопроса, по-моему, тоже

У вас в таблице должна быть колонка, отвечающая за выводимые на страницу данные.
Например, она может называться category. В этом случае код будет таким
$id = $_GET['id'] ?? 0;
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM photo WHERE category=? ORDER BY id DESC';
$result = $db->execute_query($sql, [$id]); 

